# Undefined Input Error in Basic Handling Form ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on ReactJs form with React Bootstrap Library, I got error *Undefined* when running the form in browser. In Terminal, I have no error.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        fullname: ''
    }

    this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind(this);
    this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleFullname = this.handleFullname.bind(this);
    this.submitUser = this.submitUser.bind(this);
}

handleUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        username : event.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.setState))

}

handlePassword = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        password: event.target.value
    })
}

handleFullname = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        fullname: event.target.value
    })
}
```

I tried some suggestion in handling form but still not working. here is the form i coded :

```
<Form className="salesUser text-left " variant="success" onSubmit={this.submitUser}>
    <Form.Group>
         <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
         <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsername}></Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword}></Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.fullname} onChange={this.handleFullname}></Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
    <Row>
        <Col>
            <Button type="submit" value="Submit" block>Submit</Button>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Form>
```

I tried to put console.log in handleUsername to find the error, and this is the error message when I type something in form username.

[image]

hopefully I ask the rigth question this time

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo

Comment: That screenshot isn't an error, you're logging the definition of the `setState` function. What are you trying to do and what is the problem?

Comment: @Tim I am trying to submit the form and display the data in console browser. But I got undefined error as showed in figure above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        username : event.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.setState) //**invlaid code** should be this.state but still you won't get the updated state. Instead try this as below

    this.setState({
        username : event.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.state)) //this callback function will log your updated state in console.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with

```
console.log(this.setState)
```

It takes an object to update the state, remove log and try